# Is it possible that two BroadcastReceiver from two apps, based on the same broadcast intent action, somehow "collide"?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, download-manager, cyanogenmod

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` inside a service:

```
public class NotificationClickService extends Service {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NotificationClickService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        registerReceiver(NotificationClickReceiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED));
    }

    @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(NotificationClickReceiver);
    }

    BroadcastReceiver NotificationClickReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "NotificationClickReceiver: onReceive CALLED");

                Intent i = new Intent(android.app.DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | 
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                context.startActivity(i);
        }
    };
}
```

This brings the system Download Manager to the front.

On my phone I'm running CyanogenMod 10.1 based on JellyBean.

But...

As soon as the system app CMupdater starts:

- if **CMupdater** is currently running, it is called from my service's BroadcastReceiver, instead of the `DownloadManager`;
- if **CMupdater** is not running, but *has ran* at least once, my receiver is not called at all.

It works again if I reboot and don't run the updater.
All tested also on my tablet with the corresponding CyanogenMod 10.1 version.

This is from the CM's receiver:

```
package com.cyanogenmod.updater.receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.cyanogenmod.updater.UpdatesSettings;

public class NotificationClickReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
     private static String TAG = "NotificationClickReceiver";

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         // Bring the main app to the foreground
         Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdatesSettings.class);
         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
                 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
         context.startActivity(i);
     }
 }
```

and from its manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.cyanogenmod.updater.receiver.NotificationClickReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

`android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED` is the constant value for the `DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED` intent I used.

Comment: "if it's currently running, it's called from my service's BroadcastReceiver, instead of the DownloadManager" What's running? What's called?

Comment: question edited. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. So you are registering a receiver with the action `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED`. When the user clicks on a download, every receiver will be notified. This means yours and also every other one. Have you checked the receiver is actually not being called? Perhaps the problem has to do with the new activity launch flags other than the receiver itself.

Comment: thanks to you for the comment: yes, the receiver is called (I removed the Log.d() calls from the code above). it is called but not "executed". `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is mandatory due to an exception otherwise thrown.

Comment: emendament: my receiver is not called at all (if CMupdater has ran before). editing the question.

Comment: Try commenting the `setFlags` line.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is mandatory due to an exception otherwise thrown. After reboot, when my receiver is actually called: `RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent... Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` I tried removing the other flags except this one. Then I started CMupdater. No effect. Receiver not called again.

Comment: Is CMUpdater somehow replacing the default download manager in that ROM? I mean, is the normal download manager still installed or there's only CMUpdater?

Comment: BTW, CMUpdater seems it is no longer maintained, and I can't find that receiver in [the manifest](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogen-updater/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml) (I know, this does not solve the problem, just saying)

Comment: yes the standard DownloadManager is present. About maintenance, I don't know. It's included in nightlies updates, and it seems that a commit occurred 9 days from now...

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still having trouble deciphering your question, I can't see how your receiver would have ever been called. You are missing the category registration in your intent filter.

Try:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED); 
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
registerReceiver(NotificationClickReceiver, filter);
```

That should ensure that you always receive the same broadcasts as the manifest registered receiver.

Comment: What's not clear? I'll edit the question; anyway, this is all about a receiver that works only if a system updater has never ran before. And yes, I see `Intent.CATEGORY_HOME` in the CMupdater... in the emulator works without `Intent.CATEGORY_HOME`. I'm going to try adding this, and see if it works on the phone.

Comment: Are you sure your receiver is actually registered? IF you put logs into your onCreate and onDestroy you should see whether or not your service is actually running.

Comment: `Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "service created")` yes I see this Log from `onCreate()`

Comment: These problems would imply a missing permission / package filtered intent, but that would have prevented this from ever working (which you say it does work before the updater is open). The symptoms point to an ordered broadcast that is aborted by a receiver with higher priority, but the posted code doesn't show that either. There is nothing else to prevent broadcasts from reaching you.

Answer (score 0):

All matching `BroadcastRecievers` will be notified, with their appropriate `Context`. Note that this can happen in two ways:

1. If a Receiver is locally created in code and registered, inside some object, it will be called only if that object is around.
2. If an Reciever is [declared](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) in manifest, that object will be created and `onReceive()` method will be called.

So, you can have Service class implement `BroadCastReciever`, declare it in Manifest file, and start your service form its `onRecieve()`;